# smaller file compressed by gzip is larger than the big one?

Tags: compression

I have two object files compiled by two different version of gcc:

file name     size(bytes)

a1.o        48194128

a2.o        41984052

the size of a2.o is smaller than that of a1.o.  But after being compressed by gzip,  the size of a2.o.gz is larger than the size of a1.o.gz.  What's the theory underlying?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct correlation between file size and compressed size.

I.e. sample for [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) compression (much worse than GZIP, but easier to show idea):

- File 1: {0,0,0,0} 4 bytes compresses to approximately 2 bytes {4,0}
- File 2: {1,2,3,4} 4 bytes grows to approximately 8 bytes instead of compression {1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4}

In general more random data is in the file than less compressible file is.

For compiled binaries different options may trigger extra tables to be included (like source locations) or use different (ASCII vs. UTF-16) string representation - all this may change amount of repetition in the file that compression can use to actually compress binaries.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any better compression algorithm that can overcome this weakness?

Comment: The fact that your arbitrary expectation is not met is not a weakness. If for some reason you would really like for the results of two compressions to have the same compression ratio, then pad the greater compression ratio file with zeros until they are both the same.